# setIsPlaying is not a function. Using react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react music player (ok, spotify clone). I don't know about redux and any global states So Iam learning context to change states from another components.
Edit: I am using a codesandbox example = https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-forked-6t8g7l?file=/src/LanguageSwitcher.js
As usual, I am getting error
This is my App.js =>

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import IsPlayingContext from './context/IsPlayingContext';
import styles from './style/App.module.css';
function App() {
  const [isPlaying,setIsplaying]=useState(false)
  const value = { isPlaying,setIsplaying };


  return (
    <Router >
        <div className={styles.layout}>
      <IsPlayingContext.Provider value={value} >
          {size.width > CONST.MOBILE_SIZE 
            ? <Sidebar /> 
            : <MobileNavigation />
          }
          <Switch >
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/search">
                <Search />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/library">
                <Library />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/playlist/:path">
                <PlaylistPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
      </IsPlayingContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Footer.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import IsPlayingContext from '../../context/IsPlayingContext';
function Footer(props){
    const {isPlaying,setIsPlaying} = useContext(IsPlayingContext)



        useEffect(() => {
            setIsPlaying(true)
            // That's the line 
        }, [])
        
    
    return (
        // Here my usual code
    );
}



  
export default Footer
```

The error i am getting is =>
Uncaught TypeError: setIsPlaying is not a function
at footer.js:49:1

Please help me I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo mistake, you declared setIsplaying using a small `p` i in App.js

```
const [isPlaying,setIsplaying]=useState(false)
const value = { isPlaying,setIsplaying };
```

and you are accessing it as setIsPlaying where `P` is a capital letter in the Footer component

```
const {isPlaying,setIsPlaying} = useContext(IsPlayingContext)
```

So change it too,

```
const {isPlaying,setIsplaying} = useContext(IsPlayingContext)
```

Comment: Bro thanks a lot! We want more guys like you

Comment: np, glad to help